# Invalid cast from type ‘void*’ to function pointer

Tags: c++

I want to override `open` from `libc` using `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

extern "C" {

int open(const char *path, int flags, mode_t mode)
{
    int (*originalOpen)(const char *path, int flags, mode_t mode);
    originalOpen = reinterpret_cast<decltype(originalOpen)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open"));
    //originalOpen = reinterpret_cast<decltype(open)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open"));
    //...
    return (*originalOpen)(path, flags, mode);
}

}
```

I compile with `g++ -fPIC -shared -o open.so open.cpp -ldl`.

Can somebody tell me why the above code works, and why I get the  errror:

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘int(const char*, int, mode_t)’ {aka ‘int(const char*, int, unsigned int)’}
  originalOpen = reinterpret_cast<decltype(open)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open"));
```

when I initialize `originalOpen` with the line commented out?

I used `gcc version 8.0.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
originalOpen = reinterpret_cast<decltype(open) *>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open"));
```

Decltype gets the type of the function while You want to create **function pointer**. There is implicit cast from function to pointer of its type but these are not equivalent. This is why version with `decltype(original_open)` works perfectly - type of `original_open` is function pointer and not the function.